# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app I use `react-images-upload` to upload image

And when I upload image `onDrop` function will call and in this function I convert this image file into object URL as shown in below code

**Code**

```
onDrop = (picture) => {
     const localImageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(picture[0]);
     this.props.onFabricUploadedImage(localImageUrl)

}
```

then this objectURL pass to the `onFabricUploadedImage` function to store it in `redux` state.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duTyt.png)

But when I click on `X` to remove uploaded img then it occur error as showing in above attached img

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
```

So how to fix this error after click on `X`

Comment: Are you using a FileReader for the file?

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza No

Answer (score 0):

Please, explor follow code and look official npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-upload:

```
onDrop(picture) {
    this.setState({
        pictures: this.state.pictures.concat(picture),
    });
}
```

1. when you click on Button (x) you should edit state (this.setState([])

Comment: hey but I set state in redux using  `this.props.onFabricUploadedImage(localImageUrl)` function and store objectURL in redux state